# How to return maximum value in a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose we have a matrix like this:

```
               degree        eigenvector     between
degree         1.0000000      0.9404647      0.2435627
eigenvector    0.9404647      1.00000000     0.67371624
```

I want to return the highest value (not = 1, here `0.94...`) and the lowest value (`0.243...`).

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

A `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes.  So, we could subset the matrix with a logical vector and get the `range` to return the `min/max` values excluding the 1

```
range(mat[mat != 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `range` + `diag`

```
> range(`diag<-`(mat,NA),na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0.2435627 0.9404647
```